# How to fix my code of comparing String with compareTo()

Tags: java, string, sorting, comparable

I have written this code to sort movies by name which is a String, but it is not sorting it.

Also, how should I compare two `movies` based on year attribute?

```
//public int compareTo(Movies m) { return this.year-m.year; }
```

I am confused, which m object is getting compared as we have passed the whole list in sort method.

```
import java.util.*;

class Movies implements Comparable<Movies> {
    private double rating;
    private String name;
    private int year;

    // Used to sort movies by year
    public int compareTo(Movies m) {
        return this.getName().compareTo(m.getName());

    }

    // Constructor
    public Movies(String nm, double rt, int yr) {
        this.name = nm;
        this.rating = rt;
        this.year = yr;
    }

    public void thisee() {
        System.out.println(this.year);
    }

    // Getter methods for accessing private data
    public double getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Movie> list = new ArrayList<Movie>();
        list.add(new Movie("Force Awakens", 8.3, 2015));
        list.add(new Movie("Star Wars", 8.7, 1977));
        list.add(new Movie("Empire Strikes Back", 8.8, 1980));
        list.add(new Movie("Return of the Jedi", 8.4, 1983));

        Collections.sort(list);

        System.out.println("Movies after sorting : ");
        for (Movie movie : list) {
            System.out.println(movie.getName() + " " + movie.getRating() + " " + movie.getYear());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second sentence (how the below code of compareTo if I ...) does not make much sense. Can you reword this to make your question easier to understand?

Comment: re: *I have written this code to sort name which is a String, but it is not sorting string.*   It looks (at a brief glance) like it correctly sorts by movie name.  What output are you getting that you believe to be wrong?

Comment: re: *I am confused, which m object is getting compared as we have passed the whole list in sort method*.  All of them, or something like that.  You can imagine that ```sort``` compares the 1st movie in the list against the 2nd, the 3rd, …, etc, to find the smallest value.  Then it compares the 2nd against the 3rd, the 4th, … to find the next smallest value.  (Exact comparisons performed depend on the particular sort algorithm, and my illustration chose an inefficient algorithm for clarity. It's not the actual algorithm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general contract of Comparable.compareTo(o) is to return

- a positive integer if this(Comparable) is greater than the other object(o).
- a negative integer if this is lower than the other object.
- 0 if this is equals to the other object.

So to compare the year of two movies you need to Create Integer objects for both movies and then compare them.

```
// Used to sort movies by year
public int compareTo(Movies m) {
    Integer movie1 = Integer.valueOf(this.getYear());
    Integer movie2 = Integer.valueOf(m.getYear());
    return movie1.compareTo(movie2);
}
```

Output(Sorted by year):

```
Movies after sorting : 
Star Wars 8.7 1977
Empire Strikes Back 8.8 1980
Return of the Jedi 8.4 1983
Force Awakens 8.3 2015
```

P.S Your code works fine if you want to sort by name just change the main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // The class you created is Movies not Movie (IDK if that was typo)
    ArrayList<Movies> list = new ArrayList<Movies>();
    list.add(new Movies("Force Awakens", 8.3, 2015));
    list.add(new Movies("Star Wars", 8.7, 1977));
    list.add(new Movies("Empire Strikes Back", 8.8, 1980));
    list.add(new Movies("Return of the Jedi", 8.4, 1983));

    Collections.sort(list);

    System.out.println("Movies after sorting : ");
    for (Movies movie : list) {
       System.out.println(movie.getName() + " " + movie.getRating() + " " + 
       movie.getYear());
    }
}
```

Output (Sorted by Name):

```
Movies after sorting : 
Empire Strikes Back 8.8 1980
Force Awakens 8.3 2015
Return of the Jedi 8.4 1983
Star Wars 8.7 1977
```

Comment: Thank You so much, I changed and it worked. I had made a list of type Movie, which is already a class in my workspace so it didn't throw any error.

Comment: Also, as you explained above that it will compare with this object and o object. That is what my confusion is, as we have passed the list in sort, I am unable to debug the compareTo method. How and which value of this object will be compared to which o object. Could you please help me out by explaining with the above example with one by one steps of comparison.

Comment: Does my comment above not explain the general principle, that multiple comparisons of different objects will be made?  The exact sequence depends on the algorithm and on the particular input data.  If you want to understand, I'd instrument the code: temporarily put a statement in compareTo to print out the names of the objects being compared: ```System.out.println(getName() + " : " + m.getName())```

Comment: @Agarwal This (https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-string-compareto-method-example/) explains compareTo() with examples. If you get stuck please ask.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to sometimes sort by name and sometimes sort by year, without having to modify the Movie class to do it, then you can embed the order into separate 'comparator' objects rather than in the movies that are being compared.

```
public class MoviesByName implements Comparator<Movie> {
   public int compare(Movie m1, Movie m2) {
       return m1.getName().compareTo(m2.getName());
   }
}

public class MoviesByYear implements Comparator<Movie> {
   public int compare(Movie m1, Movie m2) {
       return m1.getYear() - m2.getYear(); 
   }
}
```

and then

```
Collections.sort(list, new MoviesByName());
```

or

```
Collections.sort(list, new MoviesByYear());
```

This approach is saying that there is no single order that applies to 'Movies' - you define the order you want (via a comparator) when you do the sorting.

MoviesByRating can of course be done the same way.

P.S.  I note I incorrectly assumed the class was called Movie rather than Movies. In my opinion, 'Movie' is better because a single instance represents a single movie.  (Compare: it's Integer and not Integers).

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I was asking something different.

Comment: Fair enough - though if I can offer an opinion, I think this approach better addresses the part of the question about sorting by year. I could waffle on at length why I think that, but...  :-)

Comment: I actually like this approach though op wants to go with mine.